# Workaround for weird behaviour of SwiftUI-Menu in iOS 16

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a simple SwiftUI-view that looks like this:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextEditor(text: $textInput)
            .padding()
            .border(.blue, width: 1)
        
        HStack {
            Button("Bottom button") { print("Button pressed") }
            .padding()
            .border(.green, width: 1)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Menu("Bottom Menu") {
                Button("Menu option 1") { print("Option 1 pressed") }
                Button("Menu option 2") { print("Option 2 pressed") }
            }
            .padding()
            .border(.red, width: 1)

        }
        .background(.gray)
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the keyboard appears on this view, on a device running iOS 16, the frame of "Bottom menu" behaves really strange. It becomes even stranger if I also tap on the menu, as you can see in the screencast below.

I have tried to use `.fixedSize()` on the menu, and various other solution found here on Stack Overflow and other places, but nothing seems to work. As soon as the keyboard opens, the menu is all over the place.

When testing the same things on iOS 15, everything works as expected, so it seems to be a bug in iOS 16? Is there a workaround?

The simulator to the left is using iOS 16, and the one to the right is iOS 15.

[image: Screencast of the issue]